# Output a reserve random list (list function) in C#

Tags: c#, list

I use List function in C# and make it random parameter. This is my code. If it output a list like this: 15 20 10 3 6
How can I output again with the reseve of list above like: 6 3 10 20 15

```
List<int> dso = new List<int>(20);
Random a = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < dso.Capacity; i++)
{
   int k = a.Next(100);
   dso.Add(k);

   Console.Write("{0}  ", k);
}

for(int i=dso.Capacity;i<20;i--)
{
   Console.Write("{0} ", dso[i]);
}
```

Comment: `for(int i=dso.Capacity;i>0;i--)` use for last  for loop

Comment: Alternatively, List has Reverse() method.

Comment: You may also want to consider using a Stack<int>, rather than a List<int>.  Then you simply push the values, and they will pop in reverse order.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want `for` loop, it should be

```
for (int i = dso.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  Console.Write("{0} ", dso[i]);
}
```

Comments:

1. `Count` is the number of actual list items; `Capacity` is reserved memory
2. `List<T>` is zero based that's why `dso.Count - 1`
3. since you loop in *reversed order*, condition is `i >= 0`

However, I suggest using `String.Join` and *Linq* instead of loop and let .Net do all the work for you:

```
// List has its own Reverse() method so we have to put Reverse<int>() to use Linq one
Console.Write(String.Join(" ", dso.Reverse<int>()));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to reverse the list order then use [Reverse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0axc2h2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this:

```
dso.Reverse();

foreach (var number in dso)
{
    Console.Write(number + " ");
}
```

As you appear to be simply writing out the list in full once it's reversed you can use a [foreach loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx). If however you need more control of where you start in the list or jump around in the list then a for loop is better.